# Error when maximizing a window with TestComplete: "The window is not of the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style"

Tags: windows, jscript, testcomplete

When I try to use the `Maximize()` function for a form to make it maximized, I encountered this error.

> The window is not of the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX style.

I can see the function name `Maximize()` in the object spy reference.

I am using TestComplete with JScript for a Windows based application.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the form is not intended to be maximized. However, you still can try maximizing it using this code:

```
function maximizeNotepad()
{
  var np = Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad", 1);
  Win32API.ShowWindowAsync(np.Handle, Win32API.SW_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

If this code does not work as well then you just need to give up and work with the non-maximized form.

Comment: This works for me, Thanks